# Where to ask about new site proposal

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

If I have a question if a new Q&A site is a good idea for a site proposal, should I take the idea to Area 51? But where? There is no `meta.area51.stackexchange.com`

Comment: For Area 51 it's not "meta", but rather "discuss".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is the place.

It's also linked from the top bar on Area 51 itself for ease of access.